# Replace specific capture group values if its value equals zero

Tags: c#

Is it possible to replace specific capture group values with another value if its value equals 0 (zero) in C#?

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, "\b([1-9])([0-9])([0-9]).([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])\b");
if (match.Success)
{
    if(match.Groups[5].Value == "0" || match.Groups[6].Value == "0")
    {

    }
}
```

Basically what I have for the input is a MHz frequency, which accepts values form 100.000-199.999. What I want is if the last two digits are zeros, I want to remove them. So for example, if the input is 197.900, I want to replace it with 197.9. If it's 197.990 => 197.99. If 197.090 => 197.09...so on a so forth.

Additionally, after removing the digits, I want to rewrite the string as XXX point XXX...

```
Regex.Replace(input, "\b([1-9])([0-9])([0-9]).([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])\b", "$1 $2 $3 point $4 $5 $6");
```

I'm just not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: How long is your complete input string? Also please note that your . is not escaped, your regex accepts 199A123 etc. Use \. instead to force a period.

Comment: The input string length varies. It contains some other information, as well. However, the MHz frequency itself is XXX.XXX (including the dot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To truncate zeroes:

```
string text = "Frequencies are 193.200 and 194.220 MHz. Sometimes all three digits are used: 195.123";
string output = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b[1-9]\d{2}\.\d{3}\b", m => m.Value.TrimEnd('0'));
```

Output:

```
Frequencies are 193.2 and 194.22 MHz. Sometimes all three digits are used: 195.123
```

To truncate zeroes and replace `.` with `point`.

```
string text = "Frequencies are 193.200 and 194.220 MHz. Sometimes all three digits are used: 195.123";
string output = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b([1-9]\d{2})\.(\d{3})\b",
                              m => string.Format("{0} point {1}",
                                                 m.Groups[1].Value,
                                                 m.Groups[2].Value.TrimEnd('0')));
```

Output:

```
Frequencies are 193 point 2 and 194 point 22 MHz. Sometimes all three digits are used: 195 point 123
```

To deal with numbers having `0` decimal part, ex.: `196.000` you can use the following code:

```
string text = "193.200, 194.220, 195.123, 196.000.";
string output = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b([1-9]\d{2})\.(\d)(\d{2})\b",
                              m => string.Format("{0} point {1}{2}",
                                                 m.Groups[1].Value,
                                                 m.Groups[2].Value,
                                                 m.Groups[3].Value.TrimEnd('0')));
```

Output:

```
193 point 2, 194 point 22, 195 point 123, 196 point 0.
```

Comment: Much easier than I thought. Thanks for the clean example!

Comment: @Zach Note that it has problems with `193.000` case, it would be converted into `193.` or `193 point `. Don't know if you have such values.

Comment: After playing around with your code a bit more (the last revision you provided), it is still having trouble. If I have 193.010, it rewrites it as `193 point 1` instead of `193 point 01`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string input = "199.090";
string result = String.Empty;
Match match = Regex.Match(input, "([1-9])([0-9])([0-9]).([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])");
if (match.Success)
{
    result = match.ToString().TrimEnd(new [] {'0'});
}
result.Dump();
```

Output of `Dump()`:

199.09

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
input.TrimEnd('0');
```

This will remove the trailing 0s